# notification/alert system using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add this ability for the users of my website to request an item with several conditions being submitted in an html form by the user. And whenever there is/are item(s) with submitted conditions in my database items table(from time of submission till then), user could see them in his/her profile.

I think such system must be something like notification/alert system. I couldn't find any tutorial or anything related to this on the net.

I don't want any complete code for the above, just the method in php to code this or any related tutorials, if you know, would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried your self ! google is your friend in this case

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers I already have done several times but couldn't find good and relevant results. Maybe it's because I don't know a specific keyword for this method. Can you suggest me any good tutorials or even a specific keyword to search for. Thanks.

Comment: you can use session_id() in php as unique hash this hash must be registered in each request to check what user has complete so far. for example `<?php session_start(); echo session_id(); ?>` or if you want to register this session you can use php cookies

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers Thanks for the idea. Since I'm new to php sessions, do you know any tutorials which would explain this more? Or could you expand your above comment a little as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per your request to explain more about session and cookie

**[PHP SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)**

you can use it to register temporary variables but the php page should start with session_start

this is full example

**Page 1 example_1.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); //this should be at the top of the page

$_SESSION['myname'] = 'Jack'; //we have registered inside session ( myname = jack )
?>
```

**now in another php page example_2.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); //this should be at the top of the page

echo $_SESSION['myname'];//the output will be ( jack )
?>
```

**[PHP COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)**

if you want to store information inside user PC or laptop or machine you have to use Cookie instant of Session .

this is how to store a cookie inside user machine

```
<?php
   setcookie( 'cookieName', 'hi Jack', time()+360, '/');
?>
```

and you can call this variable `cookieName` from any other php page will output `hi Jack`

```
<?php
 echo $_COOKIE['cookieName']; //output 'hi Jack'
 ?>
```

even if user closed your project and open it tomorrow the cookie will be called from he's pc , you can read more about cookie's this will help you allot .

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer and references. Do you have any reference related to my question, using php sessions for a notification system with my question explanations?

Comment: After googling a lot, couldn't find any relevant result or tutorials. Don't you know any source or tutorial related?Thanks.